# Setting up an XML and XSLT connection asynchronously via JavaScript to remove XMLHttpRequest Console Warning

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, asynchronous, xslt-1.0

I have successfully setup a XML and XSLT connection [**on the client**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) using JavaScript, which outputs my stylised data on to a static HTML page.

However, when checking my browser console after the page has loaded, I'm getting the following `XMLHttpRequest` amber warning appearing:

[image]

I've done some background reading into this issue and the solution to removing this console error appears to be reestablishing my XML/XSLT connection ***asynchronously*** via JavaScript?

**The JavaScript File:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function loadXMLDoc(filename)
    {
        xhttp.open("GET", filename, true);
        //try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }


function displayResult(source,styledoc,dateToday)
{
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
    var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
    var xslProc;
    xslDoc.async = true;
    xslDoc.resolveExternals = false;
    xslDoc.load("bookstore.xsl");
    xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
    xmlDoc.async = true;
    xmlDoc.resolveExternals = false;
    xmlDoc.load("xml/bookstore.xml");
    xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
    xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
    xslProc.addParameter("dateToday", dateToday);
    xslProc.transform();
    ex=xslProc.output
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }

// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xml=loadXMLDoc(source);
  xsl=loadXMLDoc(styledoc);
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"dateToday",dateToday);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}

window.onload=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      displayResult('xml/course-catalog.xml','course-calendar.xsl',currentdate);
  }
};

//GET CURRENT DATE IN YYYYMMDD FORMAT

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   // return yyyy + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding - does not work on IE7
   return yyyy + (mm.slice(1,2)!=''?mm:"0"+mm.slice(0,1)) + (dd.slice(1,2)!=''?dd:"0"+dd.slice(0,1)); // padding - works on all browsers
  };
    d = new Date();
    var currentdate = d.yyyymmdd();
```

During the course of my investigation into this problem I have come across the `readyState` and `status` JavaScript properties, which monitor the loading status of the current document. Combining these properties in an *if statement*, e.g. `if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {Load the XML/XSLT};` will ensure an XML/XSLT connection isn't fired before everything on the HTML page has loaded (i.e. 4: request finished and response is ready and 200: Status "OK").

I also realise I need to change `xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);`, `xslDoc.async = false;` and `xmlDoc.async = false;` swapping the criteria over from `false` to `true` to specify I want to make my connection *asynchronously*.

Finally, I also need to incorporate an `onreadystatechange` AJAX function into the mix too, which will 'listen out' for whenever the `readyState` changes.

I'm just struggling to work out where all this would fit together in my current JS solution?

Any help and advice on this would be fantastic!

Comment: You seem to have listed all the salient points. It's hard to tell where the gaps in your knowledge are without seeing your attempt at implementing what you've learned.

Comment: The modified JavaScript code provided should hopefully show you where I've been approaching this from?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> return xhttp.responseXML;
> ```

You can't return the response before you've received it, which won't be before the request has reached Ready State 4.

> ```
> window.onload=function(){
>   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
>       displayResult('xml/course-catalog.xml','course-calendar.xsl',currentdate);
>   }
> };
> ```

You need to bind to the onload handler of *the XMLHttpRequest object* you are using. The document (represented by the window object) has already loaded.

At that point you'll need to read the data from the response (which will be in `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

Comment: So `xhttp.responseXML` needs to be positioned inside the `window.onload = function()` as opposed to the `function loadXMLDoc(filename)` where I have it displayed currently?